# How to Accept a HTML file from user and apply jQuery code on that file(GUI)

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
$(document).find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function() {
   if ($(this).parent().prev().is('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6') != true) {
       $(this).parent().before('<p>xxxxxxx</p>');
   }
});
</script>
```

For Example: User should have a option to select a HTML Page from browse option on GUI and then after that jQuery processing should be done, and then the changes done on that HTML pages , should be saved/write with another name.

Comment: The posted code doesn't at all relate to what you are asking. What have you tried thus far and where are you stuck? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/rebpb5h2/5/

Comment: it is working with pages but i want to upgrade it with user interface features.

Comment: Great! What have you tried to develop for user interface features and where are you stuck? Right now you're not even asking a question, you're requesting that someone write a program for you -  for free. The code in the fiddle is exactly the same as what's in this post, just with some html.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/rebpb5h2/5/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rebpb5h2/9/ @wahwahwah i have tried this but,it is not applying XXXXX at proper places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#button',     function() {
$('#changedContentWrapper').html($('#textarea').val());

$('#changedContentWrapper').find('.Heading-1, .Heading-2, .Heading-3, .Heading-4, .Heading-5, .Heading-6').each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().prev().is('.Heading-1, .Heading-2, .Heading-3, .Heading-4, .Heading-5, .Heading-6') != true) {
        $(this).parent().before('<p>xxxxxxx</p>');
    }
});

$('#result').val($('#changedContentWrapper').html());
```

});

above  is the solution for my question.

anyway Thanks to you all,without your help,i would never come to my solution. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '#button',     function() {
$('#changedContentWrapper').html($('#textarea').val());

$('#changedContentWrapper').find('.Heading-1, .Heading-2, .Heading-3, .Heading-4, .Heading-5, .Heading-6').each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().prev().is('.Heading-1, .Heading-2, .Heading-3, .Heading-4, .Heading-5, .Heading-6') != true) {
        $(this).parent().before('<p>xxxxxxx</p>');
    }
});

$('#result').val($('#changedContentWrapper').html());
```

});

above  is the solution for my question.

anyway Thanks to you all,without your help,i would never come to my solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Bypassing the code requirement when posting a jsfiddle link by placing code blocks around random words isn't appropriate. I'm deleting this until you edit this into a proper answer.  Feel free to flag this for moderator attention requesting that this be undeleted, once you've edited it.

Answer (score 0):

From the example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rebpb5h2/9/) you posted in the comments, it appears that you're trying to insert a `<p>` element after each `<h>` element, given some dynamic html:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {

  $('#changedContentWrapper').html($('#textarea').val());


  // setup:
  // get the header elements
  // create a new "<p>" element using jQuery selector

  var headings = $('#changedContentWrapper').find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6'),
    para = $('<p>').html('xxxxxxx');


  // no need to loop...
  // this will insert a <p> after each <h> element in your "headings" variable
  para.insertAfter(headings);


  $('#result').val($('#changedContentWrapper').html());
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
div#changedContentWrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
BEFORE
<textarea id="textarea">
  <DIV>
    <H3 CLASS="Heading-1">First Level Heading</H3> 
    <DIV>
      <H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
        <P CLASS="Tab-Text-7">Some Text Here</P>
      </DIV>


      <DIV>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1">
              Some Cotents Here
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </DIV>


      <div>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
        <TABLE>
          <TR>
            <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" class="green1">
              Some text goes here
            </TD>
          </TR>
        </TABLE>
      </DIV>


      <div>
        <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third level Heading</H6>
        <DIV>
          <H6 CLASS="Heading-4">Fourth Level Heading </H6>
          Some Text Goes here
        </DIV>
      </DIV>


      <DIV>
        <H4 CLASS="Heading-2">Second Level Heading</H4>
        <DIV>
          <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading   </H6>
          <TABLE>
            <TR>
              <TD ROWSPAN="1" COLSPAN="1" class="blue1">
                SOme text goes here
              </TD>
            </TR>
          </TABLE>
        </DIV>


        <DIV>
          <H6 CLASS="Heading-3">Third Level Heading</H6>
          Some text goes here
        </DIV>
</textarea>

AFTER
<textarea id="result"></textarea>

<button id="button">Apply Formatting</button>

<div id="changedContentWrapper"></div>
```